# protecting/authenticating JSON requests to server

Tags: php, javascript, json

i am using Ajax to send JSON data over to my server for a php script to parse.

for example this is the JSON which will be outputted:
http://myserver.com/parse.php?user=123&point=100&callback......

and the "parse.php" script will GET the points in the URL and give it to that user which the user id is stored in the user=123.

However , if a person directly use "http://myserver.com/parse.php?user=123&point=100&callback......" on their browser without letting my javascript to initiate it , they can cheat their points , which they can set to any amount they like in the URL.

So how can i protect/authenticate the JSON request??

Comment: You could do it via a POST (although it is possible to fake a POST), or maybe encrypt the points somehow. Another idea is to check if the request came from the same server (in other words, prevent direct access). For instance, check if a var is `DEFINED` (also not the best approach, but simple non the less).

Comment: Encrypting data , good idea. i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing the user points via an AJAX request or something similar client-side, then you simply cannot protect your application against cheating. Your user is telling the script he/she scored 100 points, how can you be sure that's the fair number? Pass over the initial data you're using to compute your score, like valid answers for the questions or whatever it is you're measuring.

If you have a login mechanism in your application, you could check for the valid credentials on the server-side when executing your script, without actually passing the user identifier via `GET`/`POST`.

Lastly, in your method you can check for the AJAX header and the referer (`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) to make sure the request comes from your JS code, but this is really just a minor tweak which is easy to compromize. Also, not every browser passes the referer header (depends on privacy settings), so further problems may arise.

Answer (score 0):

Require Users to be logged in to invoke parse.php.  If the request doesn't supply a valid session id, refuse to take action.

Answer (score -1):

Don't put any game data and logic in client side. 
Never trust the client. You always must calculate server-side.

More infos (don't rely on link title, there is a lot infos in answers) : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/how-do-you-prevent-your-javascript-html5-web-game-from-being-copied-or-altered

Comment: His logic is on the server side. He is just sending client data to the server. The question is about security.

Comment: Hum... sending data from client to server, and rely on thoses datas, is "putting game datas on client side". It is something that have to be avoided, in any cases. My answer is about security. You're telling him to secure his request, but he don't have to do that, he have to not rely on client request if he want to securize his datas.

Comment: i'm not working on any game. i just giving an example with points looking for a better way to secure the data. just want to learn more. :)

Comment: Game is an example, but telling you to rely on what the client is sending, is for me, a bad answer. Any person that can read your code will be able to "cheat" the datas that are sent. It can be a game, or users infos, ids, things that are put into databases... And if you really have to rely on that datas, you'll have to put strong data check server-side.
There is a lot of system to protect server-client dialog, session, validation token regenerated for each call etc... but none are 100% secured.